# Handle star imports in Python

Tags: neovim, python, lsp

I'm currently developing a lot with Python. I use projects like `pwntools` and sometimes I'm contributing to repositories that use star imports in their source code. I know that star imports are not recommended and I also know how I can avoid them when writing my own code. Nevertheless, I need to work with code that makes use of them.

Every LSP for Python spams me with messages like `'...' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: ...`.
I want warnings when something is not defined, so just disabling them is not an option. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46799137/how-to-supress-star-imports-warnings-from-spyder-ide), but that only suppresses the original warning at the import. Is there no way for the LSP to read everything from a star import to give proper warnings?

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) I suppose it depends on the LSP you are using. Maybe could you tell us which Python LSP you are using?

Comment: Hi @VivianDeSmedt, I tried all of them. It doesn't really matter to me which one I would use in the future, as long as I can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) and `coc-pyright` (run: `CocInstall coc-pyright` to install it).

It support:

```
from bar import *
```

importing your own code.

And, although it reports that wildcard import is not supported from a library, it seems to work fine for me.

```
from os.path import *
```

Comment: After some extensive research, I found that this seems a special case related to pwntools, see here: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/1644

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) I understand that the problem is a bug in pyright. The question should probably be closed.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You don't have to but you can vote to close a question ;-)